# Minecraft Command locks testfor everyone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am working on my Zombie map when I wanted to add a mechanic so that when you die you go into spectator and get to watch your team fight. I have most aspects of the mechanic working but I encountered a problem: I want to make it so when everyone is in spectator the map resets. I do this by adding three command blocks to the mechanic one to `testfor @a[m=3]` and the others just send them to the reset mechanic. I used this in a test world and for some reason it doesn't test for ALL players, just if there are anyone in spectator mode. Is there a way to test for everyone?

Comment: Yes, this is doable, but I don't have a working install of Minecraft right now, so I can't work the problem.  The short answer, though, is that the scoreboard is your friend, along with `testforblock` in this case.  Basically, you're going to use `testforblock` to see if a previous command block failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the existence of players *not* in spectator mode and invert the positive signal. In this case, you'd detect if the command block with `/testfor` had a `SuccessCount` value of 0, indicating that no players were found.

[image: Repeating > Chain > Conditional Chain]

1. Basic command to look for players not in spectator mode.

   ```
   /testfor @a[m=!spectator]
   ```
2. A `/testforblock` command that checks if the Repeating block was unsuccessful in finding any player not in spectator mode. Replace XYZ with the coordinates of the Repeating block.

   ```
   /testforblock X Y Z minecraft:repeating_command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
   ```
3. Conditional. Command to run once there are no players not in spectator mode.

   ```
   /say There are no players not in spectator mode.
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I am still new to the new update so I never realized there were more than one command block. I understand your solution and it works perfectly. I can't wait to add it to the map.